# Why is the be-verb here infinitive in "the Female Persuasion"?

Tags: meaning, the-female-persuasion, meg-wolitzer

I have been reading a book titled "the Female Persuasion."
There is a phrase with a infinitive be-verb, which I am curious about why "*be*" should be instead of am.

> "I wasn't supposed to be here at Ryland, actually. It was all a big mistake, but it happened, and it isn't fixable."
>
> "Is that right?" he asked. "You were supposed to be at another college?"
>
> "Yes. Somewhere much better."
>
> "Oh yeah? Where is that?"
>
> "Yale."
>
> He laughed. "That's a good one."
> "I *was*," she said. Then, more indignantly, "I got in."
>
> "Sure you did"
>
> I *did*. But it didn't work out, and it's too complicated to go into. So **here I be**."
>
> "**Here you be**," Darren Tinzler said.

Why in the bold text is "here I be" used instead of "here I am"? Just to emphasize it?

Answer (score 2):

"I be" is not correct grammar in standard English, but it's a form used in certain dialects. See for example [What dialect is “I be doing this”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/93231/87724) on the English Language & Usage SE - the answers don't have much in the way of supporting evidence, but at least that question makes clear that "I be" is known as a dialect form of "I am".

The character speaking in this passage, Greer Kadetsky, is from the USA (specifically Connecticut?) I don't know enough about different US accents to know if her use of this phrase is meant to tell us something about her background, or if it's just an affectation, a funny way of saying "here I am" which doesn't sound as mundane as just "here I am".

Comment: As far as I know, people in Connecticut don't typically use *Here I be* in ordinary speech.

Comment: @PeterShor Could it be a class thing? Indicating someone "from the wrong side of the railway tracks" or so?

Comment: I don't think so; *be* is definitely used in southern or AAVE non-standard dialects (I don't think this construction fits for AAVE, though). However, this is Connecticut,  and I don't think I've heard anybody from the Northeast use *be* like this.